# Instruction accesses in Gem5 for ARM processor

Tags: compilation, arm, instructions, memory-access, gem5

I used Gem5 to obtain instruction accesses for ARM processor. I used -marm option to generate code.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -static -marm fibcall.c
```

I believe that only 32-bit ARM instructions are generated using this option. But the result is shown below:

```
command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt --debug-flags=Exec configs/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/malardalen/a.out

Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
**** REAL SIMULATION ****
info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
      0: system.cpu T0 : @fini+15    :   mov.w   fp, #0           : IntAlu :  D=0x0000000000000000
    500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+3    :   mov.w   lr, #0           : IntAlu :  D=0x0000000000000000
   1000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+7    : ldmstm
   1000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+7.0  :   ldr_uop   r1, [sp, #0]   : MemRead :  D=0x0000000000000001 A=0xbeffff00
   1500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+7.1  :   addi_uop   sp, sp, #4    : IntAlu :  D=0x00000000beffff04
   2000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+9    :   mov   r2, sp             : IntAlu :  D=0x00000000beffff04
   2500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+11    : ldmstm
   2500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+11.0  :   str_uop   r2, [sp, #4]   : MemWrite :  D=0x00000000beffff04 A=0xbeffff00
   3000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+11.1  :   subi_uop   sp, sp, #4    : IntAlu :  D=0x00000000beffff00
   3500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+13    : ldmstm
   3500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+13.0  :   str_uop   r0, [sp, #4]   : MemWrite :  D=0x0000000000000000 A=0xbefffefc
   4000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+13.1  :   subi_uop   sp, sp, #4    : IntAlu :  D=0x00000000befffefc
   4500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+15    :   ldr.w   r12, [pc, #16]   : MemRead :  D=0x0000000000009039 A=0x88d8
   5000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+19    :   str.w   r12, [sp, #-4]!
   5000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+19.0  :   str.w   r12, [sp, #-4]!  : MemWrite :  D=0x0000000000009039 A=0xbefffef8
   5500: system.cpu T0 : @_start+19.1  :   subi_uop.w   sp, sp, #4  : IntAlu :  D=0x00000000befffef8
   6000: system.cpu T0 : @_start+23    :   ldr   r0, [pc, #12]      : MemRead :  D=0x0000000000008a4c A=0x88dc

...
```

We can see that at 2000, _start+9 is used, which is 2 bytes from _start+7. So I think a 16-bit instruction is used. Why is it so? Why is it not 32-bit?

Besides, does anyone know what _start+7.0 and _start+7.1 mean? Why do I have two different instructions with the same memory address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _start+7.0 and _start+7.1 are microops.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-marm` will indeed make the compiler generate ARM instructions *for the code it compiles*, i.e. the contents of fibcall.c. The `_start` symbol is not part of that code, though - that's part of the standard libraries provided by that toolchain which you statically linked in, and *those* clearly contain Thumb-2 instructions. If you want a static binary which is 100% pure ARM code with no interworking and don't have a suitable proper sysroot to compile against, then you'll need to check if that toolchain has an appropriate multilib option to provide ARM libraries instead of the Thumb ones, or find/build a suitable replacement set of libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used another toolchain
    arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.
In this case, no Thumb-2 instructions are used I think.